# When/where to use property tags of django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have model with a property that returns true or false if the start date is the current date. I want to update the is_started field to True if instance.started equals True.

```
class Advert(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_started = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_date = models.DateField()

    @property
    def started(self):
        today = str(datetime.date.today())
        start_date = str(self.start_date)

        if today == start_date:
           return True
        return False
```

My question now is where to I check for this condition. I don't know if check for this condition and update the is_started field in my views of check in the front end and send an api request to update if the condition id true. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect as per your field name, `is_started` would only ever be true if you check the value on the same day as you call the property so it doesn't make sense.

If you're talking about querying, you don't need it, you just need to check if the current date is greater than the start date

```
.filter(start_date__gte=datetime.now())
```

If you're talking about in a view or method, then your property as is (and later fixed) suffices.

Hence, the model field isn't required.